# Bootstrap 3 - Jumbotron Behind Transparent Navbar and Jumbotron Contents Centered Vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a simple landing page using Boostrap 3. I'm having trouble getting the contents of my jumbotron to be vertically centered. I'm also having trouble getting the jumbotron to show through my transparent navbar; it's currently pinned to the bottom of the navbar. Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Normalize.CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <title>Hair by Dennis</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hair by Dennis</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

        <!-- Jumbotron -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h1>Hair by Dennis</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <!-- Triggers Modal -->
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline sharp" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#makeAnAppointmentModal">Make an Appointment</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar, .jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    background: none;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: #F44336;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #F44336;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.jumbotron {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #F44336;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 520px;
}

/***********************
  OUTLINE BUTTONS
************************/

.btn.outline {
    background: none;
    padding: 12px 22px;
}
.btn-primary.outline {
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
}
.btn-primary.outline:hover, .btn-primary.outline:focus, .btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #F44336;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active {
    border-color: #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/***********************
  CUSTOM BTN VALUES
************************/

.btn {
    padding: 14px 24px;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
}

.sharp {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Please let me know if my questions are unclear. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS and the vertical centering should work:

```
.jumbotron > .container {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thnaks! Thats fixed the vertical align problem, but the navbar is still on top of the jumbotron. Do you know how to make it overlay the jumbotron?

Comment: Perhaps you could give the jumbotron a negative top margin. `margin-top: -20px;` you'll have to figure out the exact measurement, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi **Mason Walton**, Just add this to your css if your navbar is 50px in height. `body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}`